# What does "Allow Remote Clients" and "Allow Remote Administration" mean in MSDTC?

Tags: msdtc

I am trying to configure MSDTC for some production machines and am having some difficulty learning what all the settings mean, in particular, "Allow Remote Clients" and "Allow Remote Administration" under "Client and Administration."

After hours of searching, this is what I found:

- [New Functionality in [DTC]...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899191) - Documents all the settings for the MSDTC Security Configuration dialog except for these settings.
- [Troubleshooting Problems with MSDTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924%28BTS.10%29.aspx) - Provides the default and "recommended" settings, but doesn't explain what they mean.

Any help with these settings would be appreciated. If possible, I would love to have the Microsoft link to the documentation for these settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Allow Remote Clients:** Select this check box if you want this DTC to coordinate transactions for remote clients.

**Allow Remote Administration:** Select this check box if you want to allow administration of this DTC from remote computers.

From the Component Services Administration help file, located at: C:\Windows\help\mui\0409\comexp.chm, for future reference.

Comment: This has been driving me crazy. I guess I've been spoiled by Google and never thought to look on my computer :). Of course, I still am not sure what this means when using TransactionScope, but at least I have something more to go on. Thanks!